# How can I append new data rows to an existing data extension with predefined properties and columns?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, iteration, data-import

There is [data-extension-row-update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/data-extension-row-update.htm) and [data-extension-row-create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/data-extension-row-create.htm), but nothing like

> data-extension-row-append.

Say I have an existing data extension I retrieve via

```
import ET_Client
myClient = ET_Client.ET_Client()
dataextensionrow = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension_Row()
dataextensionrow.auth_stub = myClient
dataextensionrow.Name = 'ExampleDEName'
```

how can I possibly **append a row to an existing SFMC data extension** just like in a CSV or tabular structure (e.g. a pandas.DataFrame), for instance appending another row to the following:

```
index, col1, col2, col3
0, val1, val2, val3
```

which could look like

```
1, foo, baz, bar
```

**PS:**
This is not about how to construct a Python dictionary or pandas.DataFrame. I just made this analogy in order to illustrate what I hope is possible with SalesForce data extensions: appending rows to them on-the-fly.

Comment: Can't you just build your own function that will be converting your list into a dictionary?

Comment: Apparently there is a misunderstanding.
It's not about building a dict (in Python or whatever), I just wanted to make the analogy how I understand adding new "rows" to a SFMC data extension would work (in my imagination).

Comment: Ah, OK. In practice we could say that in most cases appending a new row will be the same as creating it. It's important to know if the data extension has a primary key or not. If there will be none, you can create duplicate rows with the same data (appending copies as you please), but if there will be a key, only one row would be created and attempts to add the exact same row should fail.

Comment: Well @RafałWolsztyniak, thanks for your explanation. It's been useful to understand the distinction between overriding and creating etc., but still one aspect didn't get answered and I felt like it was necessary to pose a separate question for that to make my point more clearly. If you're familiar with these topics, I'd be delighted if you could answer the following question as well: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363073/create-new-row-in-existing-data-extension